# How to get error number of array value

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, excel-2010

I've simplified my example to keep it short and placed the following values in range A1 to A4.

`A1 = 0`
`A2 = empty 'blank cell`  
`A3 = match(0;0;0) 'to produce #N/A` 
`A4 = 4,95`

I would like to catch the error number triggered in `A3`, what's already stored in the array, 
and I want to print only the positive values.

- test1 => produces a runtime error 13, even if I've checked for `IsError`.
- test2 => skips the error what's very tricky.
- test3 => In my opinion this is the best solution but I don't know how to get error number.

  ```
  Sub test1()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim arr() As Variant
  arr = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A4").Value
  For i = 1 To 4
          If Not IsError(arr(i, 1)) And Not IsEmpty(arr(i, 1)) And arr(i, 1) <> "0" Then
          MsgBox arr(i, 1)
          End If
  Next i
  End Sub
  ```

  ```
  Sub test2()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim arr() As Variant
  arr = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A4").Value
  On Error Resume Next
  For i = 1 To 4
          If Not IsEmpty(arr(i, 1)) And arr(i, 1) <> "0" Then
          MsgBox arr(i, 1)
          End If
  Next i
  End Sub
  ```

  ```
  Sub test3()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim arr() As Variant
  arr = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A4").Value
  For i = 1 To 4
          If IsError(arr(i, 1)) = True Then
          MsgBox "error at position " & i
          ElseIf Not IsEmpty(arr(i, 1)) And arr(i, 1) <> "0" Then
          MsgBox arr(i, 1)
          End If
  Next i
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: What do you mean by error number? Your code is detecting error at position 3.

Comment: In locals windows  I see error 2042 but I can't check with if statement.

Comment: on a side note, `If IsError(arr(i, 1)) = True`, why the `= True`?

Comment: In Text 3, `MsgBox CStr(arr(i, 1))` --> Error 2042

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `sub test1` is that `VBA` tries to evaluate all conditions in `AND` even if one condition is already `FALSE`. So the error is thrown from `...arr(i, 1) <> "0"...` which tries comparing an `Error` with a `String`.

```
Sub test1()
 Dim i As Long
 Dim arr() As Variant
 arr = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A4").Value
 For i = 1 To 4
  If Not IsError(arr(i, 1)) Then
   If Not IsEmpty(arr(i, 1)) Then
    If arr(i, 1) <> "0" Then
     MsgBox arr(i, 1)
    End If
   End If
  End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

should run without runtime error.

Knowing this you could do:

```
Sub test1()
 Dim i As Long
 Dim arr() As Variant
 arr = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A4").Value
 For i = 1 To 4
  If Not IsEmpty(arr(i, 1)) Then
   If IsError(arr(i, 1)) Then
    MsgBox CStr(arr(i, 1))
   ElseIf arr(i, 1) <> "0" Then
    MsgBox arr(i, 1)
   End If
  End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

The explicit conversion using `CStr` is necessary because `VBA` will not implicit convert `Error` to `String` while it does implicit convert `Double` to `String` like with `0`-> `"0"` and  `4.95` -> `"4.95"`

If only the error number is needed, then explicit conversion using `CLng` will also be possible.

```
If IsError(arr(i, 1)) Then 
 ... 
 ...CLng(arr(i, 1))
 ...
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, i wasn't familiar with `CStr` and I've removed `=true` at `IsError`